# Javascript - Why won't the innerHTML of the <h1> tag change?

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I'm trying to change my  tag's innerHTML through Javascript in the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var doSomethingAJAX = function (el, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () { 

        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        var tab = tabs[0];
        var taskName = data.data[0].name;
        alert(tab + " - " + taskName);
        var taskId = data.data[0].id;
        tab.innerHTML = taskName;
        getFormProperties(taskId);

    };
    xhr.onerror = function () { alert("error") };
    xhr.send();
};

code continues.....
```

The alert displays [object HTMLHeadingElement] and the task name correctly but it won't change the innerHTML the way it should. Am I missing something obvious?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/apitest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "css/tabs.css";</style>
<title>Tabs and REST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='tab-container'>
        <div class="tab-content">
                <h1 class="tab" title="title for page 1">Page 1</h1>
                <form id="form" action="CompleteTask" method="post">
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
                <h1 class="tab" title="title for page 2">Page 2</h1>
                <p>This is the content of tab 2 on container 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
                <h1 class="tab" title="title for page 3">Page 3</h1>
                <p>This is the content of tab 3 on container 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onload` is non-standard event for xhr and is only documented to work in Firefox. Use `onreadystatechange` instead. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: taskName is most probably undefined, fix this.

Comment: @vtz the alert displays taskName correctly.

Comment: hm this is interesting, ok move the alert after innerHTML part, see if taskName still is not undefined, also you can read more about ajax problems here - >http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search?updated-max=2012-10-31T15:44:00Z&max-results=7&start=7&by-date=false, and debug more :)

Comment: @vtz I moved the alert after the innerHTML part and it's still not undefined.

Comment: @NeedsHelp try this and c if helps, tab.textContent = taskName; if not, you need to search your problem in the ajax in my opinion